# Time stamp with Zone information

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting, timezone

I have a requirement to get time stamp with zone information as

```
2014-12-05T08:37:25+0300
```

To achieve this I used time format as

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

but it gave me the output as this format

```
2014-12-05T08:37:25Z
```

Can anybody have idea on how to get timezone information in this format

```
2014-12-05T08:37:25+0300
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
 var now = DateTime.Now;
 Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
                    + now.ToString("zzz").Replace(":", string.Empty));
```

removing ":" from zzz format string is not a built in function in .NET and easiest way to remove it is by replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

> but it gave me the output as this format 2014-12-05T08:37:25Z

This is normal because `Z` is not a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) date and time format. That's why this character is copied to the result string *unchanged*.

I think your `CurrentCulture` represents [UTC Offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) with `+0300` format without [`TimeSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can directly use [The `"K"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier) since `DateTime.Now` returns `Local` as a `DateTimeKind` like;

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK");
```

result *probably* will be;

```
2014-12-05T08:37:25+0300
```